# python: beautifulsoup4: scraping: Unable to figure out the Error

Tags: beautifulsoup, python-3.6

Here is the code I wrote to find all the product names from a page of snapdeal.com

Code:

```
import urllib.request
   from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

   url = 'https://www.snapdeal.com/products/electronics-headphones sort=plrty'

   response = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
   soup = BS(response, 'html.parser')
   product_name={}
   i=0
   for title in soup.find_all('p', class_="product-title"):
           product_name[i]=title.string
           i += 1
   for i in range(1,21):
       print(product_name[i])
```

Output:

**Traceback (most recent call last):**

Motorola Pulse 2 Over Ear Wired Headphones With Mic (Black)

Bose SoundLink On-Ear Bluetooth Headphones - Black & Blue

Sony MDR-ZX110A Headphones Without Mic (White)

Philips SBCHL140/98 Over Ear Headphone Without Mic

**File "C:/Users/Aritra Bhattacharjee/PycharmProjects/PythonWebModules/Web Scraper.py", line 17, in**

Intex Desire BT Over Ear Wired With Mic Headphone Black

```
**print(product_name[i])**
```

JBL T450 On Ear Wired Headphones With Mic Black

**KeyError: 20**

Motorola Pulse Max Over Ear Wired Headphones With Mic (Black)

Philips SHB7250WT/00 Over Ear Wireless Headphones With Mic White

Sony MDR-XB650BT On-Ear Extra Bass(XB) Headphones with Bluetooth & NFC (Black)

Intex JAZZ Over Ear Wired With Mic Headphone Black

Skullcandy S5GBW-J539 On Ear Wireless Headphones With Mic Black

JBL C300SI Over Ear Wired Without Mic Headphone Black

Zoook Rocker iFit Bluetooth Wireless Headphones With Mic Black

Signature VM-46 Over Ear Wired Headphone Without Mic White

Sony MDR-G45 Over Ear Wired Without Mic Headphone- Black

Motorola Pulse Max Over Ear Wired Headphones With Mic (White)

Bose SoundTrue Around-Ear Headphones with Mic (Navy Blue) for Samsung and 
Android Devices

JBL T450 On Ear Wired Headphones With Mic Blue

Motorola Pulse 2 Over Ear Wired Headphones With Mic (White)

The Error lines in output the bold.

And furthermore I also want to gather prices of these product and print them side by side.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: There are only 20 headphones listed on the page so, Python being 0-indexed, 20 is already out of range.

Comment: thank you @RoyalTS ...I changed i=0 to i=1 and everything went well. 

Answer (score 0):

```
right_url = 'https://www.snapdeal.com/products/electronics-headphones?sort=plrty 
you_url   = 'https://www.snapdeal.com/products/electronics-headphones sort=plrty'
```

you miss a `?` in the url, and if you want to iterate with index, you can use `enumerate()`

```
soup = BS(response, 'html.parser')
product_name = [title.string for title in soup.find_all('p',class_="product-title")]
for index, value in enumerate(product_name):
    print(index, value)
```

out:

```
0 Sony MDR-ZX110 On Ear Wired Headphone Without Mic White
1 Motorola Pulse 2 Over Ear Wired Headphones With Mic (Black)
2 Bose SoundLink On-Ear Bluetooth Headphones - Black & Blue
3 Sony MDR-ZX110A Headphones Without Mic (White)
4 Philips SBCHL140/98 Over Ear Headphone Without Mic
5 Intex Desire BT Over Ear Wired With Mic Headphone Black
6 JBL T450 On Ear Wired Headphones With Mic Black
7 Motorola Pulse Max Over Ear Wired Headphones With Mic (Black)
8 Philips SHB7250WT/00 Over Ear Wireless Headphones With Mic White
9 Skullcandy S5GBW-J539 On Ear Wireless Headphones With Mic Black
10 boAt Bassheads 600 White & Blue On Ear Wired Headphones With Mic White
11 JBL T450 On Ear Wired Headphones With Mic Blue
12 JBL C300SI Over Ear Wired Without Mic Headphone Black
13 Zoook Rocker iFit Bluetooth Wireless Headphones With Mic Black
14 Intex JAZZ Over Ear Wired With Mic Headphone Black
15 Sony MDR-G45 Over Ear Wired Without Mic Headphone- Black
16 Motorola Pulse Max Over Ear Wired Headphones With Mic (White)
17 Bose SoundTrue Around-Ear Headphones with Mic (Navy Blue) for Samsung and Android Devices
18 Sony MDR-XB650BT On-Ear Extra Bass(XB) Headphones with Bluetooth & NFC (Red)
19 Motorola Pulse 2 Over Ear Wired Headphones With Mic (White)
```